# Identifying white crystals in a grey picture and creating a binary mask for them

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, mask

I have an image with a light gray background that is filled with black and white crystals:

[image: original gray image].

My goal is to create a binary mask that turns the white crystals into a white foreground and merges the black crystals and the gray background into a black background.

I am using the opencv library in python. I have tried to sharpen the image using a laplacian filter, smooth it with a gaussian filter and finally apply OTSU thresholding to create the mask with the following code:

```
img = cv.imread('image_name',1)
img_OG = cv.cvtColor(img, cv.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

kernel1 = np.array([[1, 1, 1], [1, -8, 1], [1, 1, 1]], dtype=np.float32)
imgLaplacian = cv.filter2D(img_OG, cv.CV_32F, kernel1)
sharp = np.float32(img_OG)
img_sharp = sharp - imgLaplacian
########## convert back to 8bits gray scale
img_sharp = np.clip(img_sharp, 0, 255)
img_sharp = img_sharp.astype('uint8')


########## gaussian filter
img_blur = cv.GaussianBlur(img_sharp,(5,5),0)


#########OTSU THRESHOLDING
_,img_crist_white = cv.threshold(img_blur,0, 255, cv.THRESH_OTSU)
cv.imshow('BinaryImage_cris_white', img_crist_white)
```

The problem is, I get the opposite of what I want. The white crystals are merged with the gray background and the black crystals are highlighted as foreground in the following image.

[image: Binary image]

My question is: How can I create a binary image with those white crystals on the foreground? (It's ok if the black crystals are brought to the foreground as well)

Comment: Couple of things to try: applying hist equalization may make the crystals stand out more, as the image is pretty low contrast. A closing operation may be able to vanish some of the black spots. Fourier domain high pass filtering should also be capable of extracting the crystals. Also try cv2.adaptiveThreshold.

Comment: why would you use Otsu on an image like that? why do you sharpen and then blurr the image? throwing random algorithms at your image won't help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adaptive thresholding with a suitable offset can do a very good job.

[image]

Comment: @eldesgraciado: done with proprietary software. But adaptive thresholding is no rocket science.

Comment: This is exactly what I needed!! The thing is, I tried using adaptive thresholding (I tested both with mean and Gaussian) with various offsets and I still get only the black crystals in the foreground and not the white ones. Was there any other modification to the image aside from the adaptive thresholding @Yves Daoust?

Comment: @FelipeTannusDeMori: did you try negative values ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust: I had not! I just tried that now and it worked perfectly, this solved my problem, thank you!